# What is Hand Win Percentage?

Tags: poker-night-2

One of my challenges is to "Win a Tournament With a Hand Win Percentage Greater than 25%":
[image]

What does that mean? Does it refer to the chances of winning a hand that are displayed or is it referring to the overall number of hands you played? If the latter, does it only count the hands that you participated in or all total hands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with how many hands have been played and how many you have won.  Nothing to do with the percentages shown during showdowns.

Hands won vs played are shown during blind increases.  However, quitting and rejoining a tourney seems to reset to 0 so you could exploit that near the end of the match to get >25%.